# Problem when create new Catalog in SSMS 18

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Currently I using `SSMS v18.0`.

When I want to create a new Catalog in `Integration Services Catalogs`, I have to use Azure account to continue.

Is there any ways I can create Catalog without the needs of Azure account.

Here is the screenshot for creating a new Catalog :
[image: Here]

Comment: @KamilGosciminski in SSMS 2014 yes, but for SSMS v18.0 it cant. Here is the screenshot : https://imgur.com/JcP2bX2

Comment: I didn't used SSMS 18 yet, but you can check the following link https://www.timmitchell.net/post/2017/07/03/creating-the-ssis-catalog/

Comment: Hi @Hadi, the link you provided is for SSMS 2014. But in SSMS 18 it don't have the OK button as the image attached in the post.